# how to combine cell vertically in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

It might be the most silly question in planet. how can I merge two cell values vertically in a repeated manner. as like this:

[image]

Column A and B has 400+ cells therefore it is impossible to do what I want to achieve manually.

Note: I want to merge B into A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a simple loop in VBA that runs through each cell in the data range then adds it to the output column

```
Sub Merge()

Dim data As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim output As Range
Dim i As Integer

Set data = Range("A2:B4")
Set output = Range("D2")
i = 0

For Each cell In data
    output.Offset(i, 0) = cell
    i = i + 1
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Michael it is working I want to learn what  output.Offset(i, 0) = cell
and     i = i + 1 is doing?

Comment: Read up on the Offset property. Each loop is putting the value from the current cell in the data range into the next row below the starting output range D2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221543(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INDEX function to refer to each cell. If data is in A2:B4, this formula works in any column but must start in row 2 and can then be filled down:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$B$4,ROW()/2,MOD(ROW(),2)+1)
```

The formula uses the current row as a counter. On every even row it gets a value from the first column of data and on every odd row it gets a value from the second column of data. After every 2 rows it gets values from the next row of data.

Comment: Thanks micheal do I need to paste this formula in Column A or different column basically I don''t really understand this formula

Comment: A2:B4 represents where your data is as per your example. The formula would go into E2 in your example. It can go into any column, but must start in the 2nd row and then be filled down.